# Differences between IBM Express and not-Express hdd drives

Tags: hard-drive, ibm

I'm buying some additional hdd for an IBM server: in the supplier website I see, for ex:

39M4526 IBM 250GB S-ATA HOT-SWAP 3GB/S HDD

43w7598 EXPRESS 250GB SATA HOT-SWAP 3GB/S HDD

The prices are different but they seem equals. I already have some 43w7598 and they have the hotswap enclosure. Is the difference only in the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Updated Answer

The [IBM x3550 Hard Drive Accessories Website](http://www-947.ibm.com/systems/support/supportsite.wss/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-64276&brandind=5000008) shows that both the 43W7598 and the 39M4526 marketing part numbers have the same replacement part number of 39M4529 (see screenshot below). This appears to confirm that the drives are functionally the same and only differ from a marketing offering standpoint.

[IBM x3550 250GB HDDs http://img.skitch.com/20091217-db78umky9nd6x31wracj7m1br9.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20091217-db78umky9nd6x31wracj7m1br9.jpg)

#### Original Answer

The only difference that I could find was in the type of warranty service:

- Express model 43W7598 = Limited Warranty
- non-Express model 39M4526 = Customer Replaceable Unit

To find this information, I went to [IBM's Storage Accessories & Upgrades Shop](http://www-304.ibm.com/shop/americas/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/default/CategoryDisplay?catalogId=-840&storeId=1&langId=-1&dualCurrId=73&categoryId=4611686018425093834) and then added one of each into the cart. At the next screen, I clicked on the product description for each to get the screens shown below. Going this route, both drives were priced at $139.00 each.

Based on the [IBM Express Advantage portfolio webpage](http://www-304.ibm.com/businesscenter/smb/us/en/express), it appears to me that the Express designation is just a marketing offering geared toward the midsized market. I wouldn't be surprised that they are offering the same products under different model numbers for different prices/markets.

[IBM Express 43W7598 Drive http://img.skitch.com/20091217-gk9kfsn4nah12fefcjb6d8tf8t.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20091217-gk9kfsn4nah12fefcjb6d8tf8t.jpg)

[IBM non-Express 39M4526 Drive http://img.skitch.com/20091217-r9mdua1ehyc5y5we4wj5wu956y.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20091217-r9mdua1ehyc5y5we4wj5wu956y.jpg)

Comment: thank you very much. I still don't understand why I can see them both in my supplier website with different prices [121 euro for 39M4526 and 103 euro for  43w7598]

Comment: I think the price difference is just because IBM is wanting to offer the Express model at a lower price to entice the mid-market buyers. You might want to call IBM in your country to see if there truly is a difference in the warranties of the two drives, if not I'd just buy the Express servers/options when possible, and even if the warranties are different you might still want to go with the Express HDD.

Comment: Matthew, I think like you. It seems that Express are meant for OEM. I'll dig on this and report what I find. Thank you all for your precious support

Comment: I made several investigations and yes, at the end, it seems that the express parts are for OEM and there are no differences in warranties.
Thank you Matthew